# DIV content appear overlapping for few seconds

Tags: html, telerik, radgrid, overlapping

In my application we have couple of Telerik Grids on the page with the Pagination controls. One of the control provides facility to change the page size. All the telerik grids are rendered as nested DIVs. I have Grid 1 which has default page size of 5 rows which when I change to 100, the grid data gets rendered, the Gird container DIV gets resized however the content of the GRID2 which is at the bottom of the page appears behind this newly generated content for few seconds and then the page starts to look OK.

I tried to inspect the element in the background using IE Developer tools, however the content disappear by the time I capture the element.

Another thing is this occurs only in the IE8, in google chrome it works perfectly.

On the related issue, I googleed and found a way to force the DIv to repaint by adding and removing the CSS, however that does not seem to work.

Any pointers would help.

Kind regards,

Comment: The issue is more related to the IE8 bug, which got resolved when I toggled the DIV Display CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This function worked in my case................

```
function IE8DivRenderWorkAround() {
var dataDiv = $('#MYDIVID')[0];
dataDiv.style.cssText ="display :none";
setTimeout(function()
{
var dataDiv = $('#MYDIVID')[0];
dataDiv.style.cssText ="display :block";
},500);
}
```